# Название лампочек - встроенные?

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли эти лампочки-светильники назвать настенными? Если нет, то какими, как обозначить их встроенность в ниши?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется "утопленные лампочки" или "утопленные светильники".

Для данной конкретной конструкции подходит термин "утопленные настенные светильники".